# cygwin kill background process

Tags: cygwin, kill

I can see a process with ps, but it does not appear in "tasklist" (or windows taskmanager).

```
  PID    PPID    PGID     WINPID   TTY     UID    STIME COMMAND
15356       1   16284      10496  pty2    1001 12:59:42 /cygdrive/c/Users/Application1
```

I openned terminal as Administrator. I have tried using PID, WINPID and PGID as xxxx in:

```
kill -9 xxxx
/bin/kill -f xxxx
taskkill /pid xxxx
```

None of them work.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of this problem simply by restart Cygwin. The process went away after restart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WINPID.  Go into Windows Task Manager (Win 8.1), go to the "Details" tab (older versions of Windows show PID on the process tab or may require you to enable displaying it in options). You will see the PID for each process.  Find the one matching the WINPID and kill it.

FYI, the PPID is the parent process.  1 means that the parent is gone (the instance of Cygwin that you closed).  Depending on how the command was invoked, sometimes it'll stick around in the background even after the parent goes away.  Just because the Cygwin window was closed, doesn't mean that the processes it started were stopped.  I found this to be the case when piping output and one of the commands in the pipe chain locked up.